# SQL Server OR statement issue

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I am trying to select a row where column `C5721_USER_NAME` is not starting with "ccs" or `C5721_USER_ORIGIN` is not starting by "ccs".

If either start with "ccs", I don't want that column.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T5707_ISSUES 
WHERE (C5721_USER_ORIGIN NOT LIKE '%ccs%' OR C5721_USER_NAME NOT LIKE '%ccs%')
ORDER BY C5707_ISS_ID
```

But my results are for `C5721_USER_NAME`:

```
cnewman
ctext
ccskym
lmbsiro
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `AND`

```
SELECT * 
FROM T5707_ISSUES 
WHERE (C5721_USER_ORIGIN NOT LIKE 'ccs%' AND C5721_USER_NAME NOT LIKE 'ccs%')
ORDER BY C5707_ISS_ID
```

Also, to search for something that only `starts` with `ccs` you do not have to add an `%` before it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T5707_ISSUES 
WHERE (C5721_USER_ORIGIN NOT LIKE 'ccs%' and C5721_USER_NAME NOT LIKE 'ccs%')
ORDER BY C5707_ISS_ID
```

I've replaced **or** with **and**, as when you are using OR either of the columns having value starting with those characters can come up.

Comment: The starting `%` has to go

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice that he is looking for only starting characters. Thanks.

Comment: Great, now it matches the OP's requirements perfectly

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to search for records that don't start with the value you need to change your query to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T5707_ISSUES 
WHERE (C5721_USER_ORIGIN NOT LIKE 'ccs%' AND C5721_USER_NAME NOT LIKE 'ccs%')
ORDER BY C5707_ISS_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong logic operator OR instead of AND

```
SELECT * 
FROM T5707_ISSUES 
WHERE (C5721_USER_ORIGIN NOT LIKE '%ccs%' and C5721_USER_NAME NOT LIKE '%ccs%')
ORDER BY C5707_ISS_ID
```